# How to check if ACTION_CALL activity made a connection?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, call

How can I check if `ACTION_CALL` made a connection when it returns it's result? I want to rule out situations when user cancels the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know you can't. The only thing you could know is the state of the call, such us `CALL_STATE_IDLE, CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK, CALL_STATE_RINGING`

What you are looking for is beyond android capabilities, at least with current permissions.